# Proper CSS for highlighted text with hover

Tags: html, css

Referencing this codepen: https://codepen.io/dvreed77/pen/yrwjoM.

I want to highlight some text while having the large gap between lines, and keep the hovering event constant while hovering over a single block of text. Right now, it flashes quickly on-off-on when you hit the whitespace between lines.

I've tried setting height and a few other things, but none of them do the trick and I'm a bit lost.

Code is also referenced below

```css
div {
  width: 90%; /* Adjusted to suit the JS-Snippet layout */
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2;
}

span {
  height: 2em;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit, enim eu fermentum condimentum, nulla tellus suscipit libero, quis tincidunt eros metus sed leo.</span> 
  <span>Suspendisse eu augue lectus.</span>
  <span>Sed aliquam pulvinar nibh eu vulputate. Sed venenatis eros at nisl ornare sollicitudin. Duis nec est gravida, sodales orci in, blandit magna.</span>            
  <span>Donec semper sodales lacus vel consequat.</span>
  <span>Mauris augue lectus, pretium eget dui interdum, iaculis dictum erat.</span>
  <span>Pellentesque sed nulla blandit, suscipit risus eu, malesuada justo.</span>
  <span>Fusce in dignissim magna. Quisque at tincidunt mauris.</span>
  <span>Fusce augue mauris, ornare eget lorem sed, bibendum lacinia justo.</span>
  <span>Nullam et vestibulum neque.</span>
  <span>Duis eget mauris elementum leo scelerisque dignissim accumsan tempor ex.</span>
  <span>Donec facilisis sollicitudin urna, sed efficitur ex ornare at.</span>      
  <span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</span>
  <span>Duis at sem nibh. Sed sagittis velit sed ex tincidunt gravida facilisis eu augue.</span>
  <span>Aenean dapibus sem et dolor venenatis facilisis. Sed arcu tortor, luctus id felis quis, venenatis malesuada leo. Fusce vitae semper lacus.</span>
  <span>Phasellus magna eros, lobortis a faucibus a, elementum et sem. Nunc porta auctor arcu, eu viverra tellus vestibulum id. Morbi consequat sed magna id aliquam.</span>
  <span>Donec vehicula odio nec ullamcorper ornare.</span>
  <span> Vestibulum ut ultricies neque.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: move the hover to the parent

Comment: @ZohirSalak that would alter the background for all children though, which isn't what I want

Comment: Oh i thought there was only one span

Comment: @ZohirSalak I thought same thing.

Comment: You can use CSS transition property to make this work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a *hack* using pseudo element where the idea is to make the hoverable space of the span bigger and cover the area between the lines.

```css
div {
  width: 90%; /* Adjusted to suit the JS-Snippet layout */
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2;
  position:relative; /*relative to the div and not the span !*/
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden; /*hide the overflow of the pseudo element*/
}

span {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
span:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  /* Don't set any top and bottom value! */
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100vh; /* a big height*/
  z-index:-2;
}
/*make the pseudo element on the top of all the others on span hover*/
span:hover:before {
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit, enim eu fermentum condimentum, nulla tellus suscipit libero, quis tincidunt eros metus sed leo.</span> 
  <span>Suspendisse eu augue lectus.</span>
  <span>Sed aliquam pulvinar nibh eu vulputate. Sed venenatis eros at nisl ornare sollicitudin. Duis nec est gravida, sodales orci in, blandit magna.</span>            
  <span>Donec semper sodales lacus vel consequat.</span>
  <span>Mauris augue lectus, pretium eget dui interdum, iaculis dictum erat.</span>
  <span>Pellentesque sed nulla blandit, suscipit risus eu, malesuada justo.</span>
  <span>Fusce in dignissim magna. Quisque at tincidunt mauris.</span>
  <span>Fusce augue mauris, ornare eget lorem sed, bibendum lacinia justo.</span>
  <span>Nullam et vestibulum neque.</span>
  <span>Duis eget mauris elementum leo scelerisque dignissim accumsan tempor ex.</span>
  <span>Donec facilisis sollicitudin urna, sed efficitur ex ornare at.</span>      
  <span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</span>
  <span>Duis at sem nibh. Sed sagittis velit sed ex tincidunt gravida facilisis eu augue.</span>
  <span>Aenean dapibus sem et dolor venenatis facilisis. Sed arcu tortor, luctus id felis quis, venenatis malesuada leo. Fusce vitae semper lacus.</span>
  <span>Phasellus magna eros, lobortis a faucibus a, elementum et sem. Nunc porta auctor arcu, eu viverra tellus vestibulum id. Morbi consequat sed magna id aliquam.</span>
  <span>Donec vehicula odio nec ullamcorper ornare.</span>
  <span> Vestibulum ut ultricies neque.</span>
</div>
```

Here is another idea that rely on vertical padding (that doesn't affect the layout) and `background-clip`.

```css
div {
  width: 90%; /* Adjusted to suit the JS-Snippet layout */
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2;
  position:relative; /*relative to the div and not the span !*/
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden; /*hide the overflow of the pseudo element*/
}

span {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding:1em 0; /*we increase the area*/
  background-clip:content-box; /*we show background only on content*/
}

span:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit, enim eu fermentum condimentum, nulla tellus suscipit libero, quis tincidunt eros metus sed leo.</span> 
  <span>Suspendisse eu augue lectus.</span>
  <span>Sed aliquam pulvinar nibh eu vulputate. Sed venenatis eros at nisl ornare sollicitudin. Duis nec est gravida, sodales orci in, blandit magna.</span>            
  <span>Donec semper sodales lacus vel consequat.</span>
  <span>Mauris augue lectus, pretium eget dui interdum, iaculis dictum erat.</span>
  <span>Pellentesque sed nulla blandit, suscipit risus eu, malesuada justo.</span>
  <span>Fusce in dignissim magna. Quisque at tincidunt mauris.</span>
  <span>Fusce augue mauris, ornare eget lorem sed, bibendum lacinia justo.</span>
  <span>Nullam et vestibulum neque.</span>
  <span>Duis eget mauris elementum leo scelerisque dignissim accumsan tempor ex.</span>
  <span>Donec facilisis sollicitudin urna, sed efficitur ex ornare at.</span>      
  <span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</span>
  <span>Duis at sem nibh. Sed sagittis velit sed ex tincidunt gravida facilisis eu augue.</span>
  <span>Aenean dapibus sem et dolor venenatis facilisis. Sed arcu tortor, luctus id felis quis, venenatis malesuada leo. Fusce vitae semper lacus.</span>
  <span>Phasellus magna eros, lobortis a faucibus a, elementum et sem. Nunc porta auctor arcu, eu viverra tellus vestibulum id. Morbi consequat sed magna id aliquam.</span>
  <span>Donec vehicula odio nec ullamcorper ornare.</span>
  <span> Vestibulum ut ultricies neque.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I still get a flash when moving within the same span

Comment: @dvreed77 are you sure? which browser? it's fine for me (tested on Chrome and FF)

Comment: on chrome. I wanted to send a GIF, but couldn't figure out an easy way.

Comment: @dvreed77 check the update, the back movement seems a bit tricky because all the pseudo element are above each other. I updated the place of the pseudo element

Comment: @dvreed77 added a new idea that should be better and less hacky ;)

Answer (score 2):

The only solution i can think of is to have scaffolding

```css
.main {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid;
}

span {
  height: 2em;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.scaffolding:hover>span {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="scaffolding "> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit, enim eu fermentum condimentum, nulla tellus suscipit libero, quis tincidunt eros metus sed leo.</span></div>
  <div class="scaffolding "> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit, enim eu fermentum condimentum, nulla tellus suscipit libero, quis tincidunt eros metus sed leo.</span></div>
  <div class="scaffolding "> <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit, enim eu fermentum condimentum, nulla tellus suscipit libero, quis tincidunt eros metus sed leo.</span></div>
</div>
```

---

Or borders matching background, problem with this is that you'll have to find a border width to match the font size of the text and there should no space between tags in the markup

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2;
}

span {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 8px solid #fff;
}

span:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit, enim eu fermentum condimentum, nulla tellus suscipit libero, quis tincidunt eros metus sed leo.</span><span>Suspendisse eu augue lectus.</span><span>Sed aliquam pulvinar nibh eu vulputate. Sed venenatis eros at nisl ornare sollicitudin. Duis nec est gravida, sodales orci in, blandit magna.</span><span>Donec semper sodales lacus vel consequat.</span><span>Mauris augue lectus, pretium eget dui interdum, iaculis dictum erat.</span><span>Pellentesque sed nulla blandit, suscipit risus eu, malesuada justo.</span><span>Fusce in dignissim magna. Quisque at tincidunt mauris.</span><span>Fusce augue mauris, ornare eget lorem sed, bibendum lacinia justo.</span><span>Nullam et vestibulum neque.</span><span>Duis eget mauris elementum leo scelerisque dignissim accumsan tempor ex.</span><span>Donec facilisis sollicitudin urna, sed efficitur ex ornare at.</span><span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</span><span>Duis at sem nibh. Sed sagittis velit sed ex tincidunt gravida facilisis eu augue.</span><span>Aenean dapibus sem et dolor venenatis facilisis. Sed arcu tortor, luctus id felis quis, venenatis malesuada leo. Fusce vitae semper lacus.</span><span>Phasellus magna eros, lobortis a faucibus a, elementum et sem. Nunc porta auctor arcu, eu viverra tellus vestibulum id. Morbi consequat sed magna id aliquam.</span><span>Donec vehicula odio nec ullamcorper ornare.</span><span> Vestibulum ut ultricies neque.</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: I arrived at something similar, but then the sentences don't flow from one to another like they would normally in a paragraph of text.

Comment: `I want to highlight some text while having the large gap between lines, and keep the hovering event constant while hovering over a single block of text` keyword there is `block` if you would expand the snippet you provided to full screen you would see that some lines start at the middle and end the beginning of the next line, now trying to keep the hovering effect alive won't be possible  because you'll be hovering over other text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS transition property to make this happen. Specifically, you introduce a transition delay on mouseout but no delay on hover.

SO... what will happen is that on hover the background will change, but on mouseout it takes a full second (or 1.25s or 2s or etc) for the background transition to kick-in. *IF the user moves onto another span, the background change will be over-ridden/cancelled (so to speak), keeping the background color unchanged. The end result is exactly what you have requested.*

The magic here is to add both of these CSS directives:

```
span      {transition:background-color 0s ease-out 1s;} /* 1s delay on mouseout */
span:hover{transition:background-color 0s ease-out 0s;} /* No delay on hover */
```

```css
div {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 2;
}

span {
  height: 2em;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: background-color 0s ease-out 1s; /*  1s delay on mouseout */
}

span:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
  transition: background-color 0s ease-out 0s; /*  No delay on hover */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit, enim eu fermentum condimentum, nulla tellus suscipit libero, quis tincidunt eros metus sed leo.</span> 
  <span>Suspendisse eu augue lectus.</span>
  <span>Sed aliquam pulvinar nibh eu vulputate. Sed venenatis eros at nisl ornare sollicitudin. Duis nec est gravida, sodales orci in, blandit magna.</span>            
  <span>Donec semper sodales lacus vel consequat.</span>
  <span>Mauris augue lectus, pretium eget dui interdum, iaculis dictum erat.</span>
  <span>Pellentesque sed nulla blandit, suscipit risus eu, malesuada justo.</span>
  <span>Fusce in dignissim magna. Quisque at tincidunt mauris.</span>
  <span>Fusce augue mauris, ornare eget lorem sed, bibendum lacinia justo.</span>
  <span>Nullam et vestibulum neque.</span>
  <span>Duis eget mauris elementum leo scelerisque dignissim accumsan tempor ex.</span>
  <span>Donec facilisis sollicitudin urna, sed efficitur ex ornare at.</span>      
  <span>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</span>
  <span>Duis at sem nibh. Sed sagittis velit sed ex tincidunt gravida facilisis eu augue.</span>
  <span>Aenean dapibus sem et dolor venenatis facilisis. Sed arcu tortor, luctus id felis quis, venenatis malesuada leo. Fusce vitae semper lacus.</span>
  <span>Phasellus magna eros, lobortis a faucibus a, elementum et sem. Nunc porta auctor arcu, eu viverra tellus vestibulum id. Morbi consequat sed magna id aliquam.</span>
  <span>Donec vehicula odio nec ullamcorper ornare.</span>
  <span> Vestibulum ut ultricies neque.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but the delay after the final exit isn't what I want.

Comment: [Temani Afif's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55894906/1447509) looks like the best solution !